# How to unit test an Express Controller with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have been getting terribly confused with how to test my controller functions. I realize that I have to mock my dependencies, request, response, and the controller functions. Here's what I have so far:

OrdersController.js

```
  const OrderService = require('../services/orderServices')

  module.exports = class OrdersController {
    static async apiGetOrders(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const orders = await OrderService.getOrders()
        return res.status(200).json(orders)
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Unable to get orders' }) // 500, Internal Service Error, generic
    }
  }

  static async apiPostOrder(req, res, next) {
    // All good, create an orderDocument
    try {
      const orderDocument = {
        _id: null, // undefined at this point Mongo creates this _id for us
        orderId: req.body.orderId,
        cookies: req.body.cookies,
        daySelected: req.body.daySelected,
        timeSelected: req.body.timeSelected,
        userInfo: req.body.userInfo,
        createdAt: new Date(),
      }
      await OrderService.addOrder(orderDocument)
        return res.status(201).send('success') // status OK, something was Created
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error }) // 500, Internal Server Error
    }
  }
```

OrdersController.spec.js

```
import OrderService from '../services/orderServices'
import { mockOrder, mockOrders } from '../mocks/fixtures'
import OrdersController from '../controllers/ordersController'
jest.mock('../controllers/ordersController.js')


const mockRequest = () => {
  return {}
}
const mockResponse = (mockOrders) => {
  const res = {};
  res.status = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(200);
  res.json = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockOrders);
  return res;
}


// #3 Test the OrdersControllers
// mock dependencies: req, res, and spyOn the controller functions

describe('Orders Controller', () => {
  test('[Positive], should call OrderService.getOrders and receive status 200', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(OrdersController, 'apiGetOrders')
    const req = mockRequest()
    const res = mockResponse(mockOrders)
    await OrdersController.apiGetOrders(req, res)
    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200)
    expect(res.json()).toEqual(mockOrders)
  })
  test('[Negative], error yields status 500', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(OrdersController, 'apiGetOrders')
    const req = mockRequest()
    const res = mockResponse({status: 500, error: 'Unable to get orders'})
    await OrdersController.apiGetOrders(req, res)
    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(500)
    expect(res.json()).toEqual(error)
  })
})
```

I'm trying to test the happy path and the negative path on the get request. I followed this expample, https://codewithhugo.com/express-request-response-mocking/, and read all of the jest docs, https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions. The error that I receive is:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Am I actually writing the tests correctly?
2. Am I also supposed to mock the OrderService?
3. Should I use Sinon or is Jest more than sufficient?

Comment: _Don't_ unit test controllers. So much of what you're mocking you don't even own. Use an integration level test like Supertest.

Comment: Interesting, it never occurred to me that I don't own the request and response. Should I at least spyOn the Orderservice.getOrders(), since that is expected to be called?

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to Jest and am struggling with finding documentation that goes to enough detail to suggest to me what I'm doing wrong. But in your case, I think you might be spying on the wrong thing. The OrdersController is the subject of the test, so I don't believe that you should be mocking that. Rather you should spy on OrdersController's dependency, Orderservice and mock its methods.

Also, its not clear to me why you have `next` in

```
static async apiGetOrders(req, res, next)
```

You don't seem to use it in the body of the method anywhere, so hanging any testing off that value, probably won't work either.